# jqgrid - can I access server response with onSelectRow?

Tags: json, jqgrid

I get a JSON response from the server that I have full access to using `loadComplete`. Is it possible to be able to access the JSON response using

1. `onSelectRow`?
2. any other custom function defined outside of `loadComplete`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a variable which will hold the last state of the JSON response returned from the server:

```
var serverData;
$('#list').jqGrid({
    datatype: 'json',
    // ... other parameters
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        serverData = data; // or serverData = data.rows
        // ...
    },
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        if (serverData) {
            // here you can access serverData, but you need
            // here probably find the item in the serverData
            // which corresponds the id
        }
    }
});
```

If you have JSON data for example from the form

```
{
  "total": "xxx",
  "page": "yyy",
  "records": "zzz",
  "rows" : [
    {"id" :"1", "cell": ["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {"id" :"2", "cell": ["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
      ...
  ]
}
```

then you can save in `serverData` not the data directly. It could be interesting to save only `cell` part and save it as the value of the `serverData[id]`:

```
var serverData = [];

$('#list').jqGrid({
    datatype: 'json',
    // ... other parameters
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        var i, rows = data.rows, l = rows.length, item;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            item = rows[i];
            serverData[item.id] = item.cell;
        }
        // ...
    },
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        var item = serverData[id]; // the part of data which we need
    }
});
```

If you use `repeatitems: false` setting in the `jsonReader` then you can save in the `serverData` only the part of the items (selected properties) which represented the row of the server data.

In any way you should save the part of the information from `data` parameter of `loadComplete` in some variable defined *outside of* the `loadComplete`.

Comment: can you please take a look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564806/jqgrid-error-when-moving-from-1-page-to-another