# jqgrid - error when moving from 1 page to another

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have a large data set coming back in JSON format such that I get 3 pages, each page has 5 rows.

**JSON**

```
{
   "mypage":{
      "outerwrapper":{
         "page":"1",
         "total":"3",
         "records":"15",
         "innerwrapper":{
            "rows":[
               {
                  "id":"1",
                  "read": true,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                         "label":"linkimg",
                         "value": "Link-A",
                         "links": [
                             {
                                 "name":"link1"
                             },
                             {
                                 "name":"link2"
                             },
                             {
                                 "name":"link3"
                             }
                         ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"2",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-B",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"3",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-C",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"4",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-D",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"5",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-E",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"6",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-F",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"7",
                  "read": false,                  
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-G",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"8",
                  "read": false,                  
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-H",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"9",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-I",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"10",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-J",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"11",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-K",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"12",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-L",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"13",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-M",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"14",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-N",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"15",
                  "read": true,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "value": "Link-O",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**JQGrid Definition**

```
$("#myjqgrid").jqGrid({
   url: "jqgrid.json",
   datatype: "json",
   contentType: "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8",
   colNames:['linkimg'],
   colModel:[
      {name:'linkimg',index:'linkimg', width:100, align:"center", resizable:false}
   ],
   jsonReader: {
       root: "mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows",
       repeatitems: false
   },
   rowNum:5,
   rowList:[5,10,15],
   pager: '#Pager',
   sortname: 'id',
   recordpos: 'left',
   multiboxonly:true,
   viewrecords: true,
   sortorder: "desc",
   multiselect: true,
   width: "1406",       
   height: "100%",      
   scrolloffset: 0, 
   loadonce: true,      
   sortable: true,      
   sorttype: "text"
})
```

**What I'm trying to do**

*I'm looping through each row in JSON and checking for the `"read"` property. If it is `true`, then that row should have css `text-decoration` set to `underline`.*

```
loadComplete: function(data){
    var x, rowItem;         
    for (x = 0; x < data.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows.length; x++) {
        rowItem = data.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows[x];
        var rowItemRead = rowItem.read;
        if(rowItemRead === true){                   
            $("#" + rowItem.id + " > td").css({"text-decoration":"underline"});
        }
    }
}
```

**The above piece of code is working BUT the problem is**

When I navigate from page 1 to page 2 OR from page 2 to page 3, I get the error message

```
mypage.outerwrapper
```

is null or not an object.

**Full JQGrid definition code (with jsonReader and loadComplete)**

```
$(function (){
    var getValueByName = function (cells, cellItem) {
        var i, count = cells.length, item;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
            item = cells[i];
            if (item.label === cellItem) {
                return item.value;
            }
        }
        return '';
    };
    $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid({
        url: "jqgrid.json",
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8",
        colNames:['linkimg'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'linkimg',index:'linkimg',jsonmap:function(obj){return getValueByName(obj.cells, "linkimg");}, width:50, align:"center", resizable:false},
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            root: "mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows",
            page: "mypage.outerwrapper.page",
            total: "mypage.outerwrapper.total",
            records: "mypage.outerwrapper.records",
            repeatitems: false
        },
        rowNum:5,
        rowList:[5,10,15],
        pager: '#Pager',
        recordpos: 'left',
        multiboxonly:true,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        multiselect: true,
        width: "1406",      
        height: "100%",     
        scrolloffset: 0,    
        loadonce: true,     
        sortable: true,     
        sorttype: "text",
        cache: true,
        loadComplete: function(data){
            var x, items, idName, rowItem;  
            if (typeof data.mypage === "undefined") {
                items = data.rows;
                idName = '_id_';
            }else{
                items = data.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows;
                idName = 'id';
            }
            for (x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
                rowItem = items[x];
                var rowItemRead = rowItem.read;
                if(rowItemRead === true){

                    $("#" + rowItem[idName] + " > td").css({"text-decoration":"underline"});
                }
            }           
        }
    });
    $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#Pager',{add:false,del:false,edit:false,position:'right',minWidth:800,maxWidth:1405,minHeight:350,maxHeight:680});
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(function (){
    var getValueByName = function (cells, cellItem) {
        var i, count = cells.length, item;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
            item = cells[i];
            if (item.label === cellItem) {
                return item.value;
            }
        }
        return '';
    };
    var setCSS = function (rowId, val, rawObject){
        return rawObject.read? ' style="text-decoration: underline;"' : '';
    }
    $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid({
        url: "jqgrid.json",
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8",
        colNames:['linkimg','read'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'linkimg',index:'linkimg',jsonmap:function(obj){return getValueByName(obj.cells, "linkimg");}, width:50, align:"center", resizable:false, cellattr:function(obj){return setCSS(rowId, val, rawObject);}},
            {name:'read', hidden:true}
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            root: "mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows",
            page: "mypage.outerwrapper.page",
            total: "mypage.outerwrapper.total",
            records: "mypage.outerwrapper.records",
            repeatitems: false
        },
        rowNum:5,
        rowList:[5,10,15],
        pager: '#Pager',
        recordpos: 'left',
        multiboxonly:true,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        multiselect: true,
        width: "1406",      
        height: "100%",     
        scrolloffset: 0,    
        loadonce: true,     
        sortable: true,     
        sorttype: "text",
        cache: true
    });
    $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#Pager',{add:false,del:false,edit:false});
});
```

Comment: If `"jqgrid.json"` is URL to the file or is the URL where the server dynamically generate the data which represent the requested page?

Comment: `"jqgrid.json"` is a URL to a local JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `datatype: "json"` without `loadonce: true` then the `url: "jqgrid.json"` should *dynamically+ generate the requested page and the **server** is responsible for sorting, paging and filtering of data.

If you load *static* JSON data per Ajax, for example if the "jqgrid.json" is just a file, then you should use `loadonce: true` option of jqGrid. In the case jqGrid with load the data *only once* and cache it locally in the internal parameters `data` and `_index`. Then paging, sorting and filtering of the data will be made by jqGrid locally on the client side.

**UPDATED**: After the first load the format of the `data` parameter of `loadComplete` callback *will be changed* and will have the names corresponds to [localReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data). So you can just test inside of `loadComplete` whether `typeof data.mypage === "undefined"`. In the case the `loadComplete` works already with the *local* data and you will find the items the grid which will be displayed on the current page as the items of the array `data.rows`. So the code can be about the following:

```js
loadComplete: function(data){
    var x, rowItem, items, idName, l;         
    if (typeof data.mypage === "undefined") {
        // load from the local data
        items = data.rows;
        idName = '_id_';
    } else {
        items = data.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows;
        idName = 'id';
    }
    for (x = 0, l = items.length; x < l; x++) {
        rowItem = items[x];
        if(rowItem.read === true){                   
            $("#" + rowItem[idName] + " > td").css({"text-decoration":"underline"});
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED 2**: After you posted full code with the test data everything will be clear. How you can see from [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11-2.htm) if you just add additional hidden column

```
{name:'read',hidden:true}
```

the grid will display the data correctly.

I wrote you before that the current code from `loadComplete` is not effective. Now I can give you the suggestion what you can do. You can first add the hidden `'read'` column (see above) and additionally add `cellattr` property to the `'linkimg'` column defined as following

```
cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject) {
    return rawObject.read? ' style="text-decoration: underline;"' : '';
}
```

After that **you can remove the full code which you use in `loadComplete`**. How you can see from the [next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11-2_.htm) the approach works. The code will be not only clear, but it works much more quickly.

The last remark: I added in both demos the parameter `gridview: true` which improve the performance without any disadvantages in your case. I recommend include the parameter in all your grids.

Comment: I've updated my **jqgrid definition**. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @SK11: I updated my answer with additional information. It should solve your problem. If you would have performance problems in `loadComplete` of your solution I recommend you to look in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575634/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5690583/315935) which describe another way how to iterate through the data in the `loadComplete`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not getting any error message now. BUT, as I navigate from one page to another, the css `underline` state is lost for that row.

Comment: @SK11: Could you post more full code which you use. You current code has no `jsonReader` which are required to read the data which you use. You posted `loadComplete` also *outside* of the grid definition. Could you post the code which can be used to reproduce your problem?

Comment: My current code has `jsonReader`. But I've posted the full jqgrid definition for you under the heading **Full JQGrid definition code (with jsonReader and loadComplete)**.

Comment: @SK11: What I mean is that your JSON data contains complex `"cells"` whicj don't corresponds the `jsonReader` which you use. You have at least define `jsonmap`. So If I use the code to read your JSON data I see an empty grid.

Comment: @SK11: Another problem which you has. you don't save the information `read` in any column of the grid. So if you goes to the next page the `rowItem.read` will be always `undefined`. Because I don't understand which information you place in the `linkimg` column I can't help you to fix the problem.

Comment: I've updated the `colModel` (forgot about it earlier). You should be able to see the grid. There are 2 columns - the first column is for the checkboxes. The second column displays the value of `value` property under `cells`.

Comment: @SK11: Now everything is clear. See "UPDATE 2" part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Another one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508389/jqgrid-json-looping-issue

Comment: I am trying to define a generic function for `cellattr` that can be used for any number of cells/columns. Please see my post under **UPDATE**. It's giving me an error message **`rowId` is undefined**

Comment: @SK11: You should replace `cellattr:function(obj){return setCSS(rowId, val, rawObject);}` to `cellattr: setCSS`

Comment: Thank you so much. I need your help on this pls - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581897/jqgrid-rendering-javascript-file-with-the-column-model